# What should I write in hostname when I try to install a theme?

Tags: localhost

I am a beginner with WordPress and I have no idea what hostname I should specify when I try to install a theme. Thank you for a help! [image]

Comment: This only appears if the folder is read only and WordPress can't directly modify the folder. Check your file permissions and folder ownership for the `wp-content/themes` folder are set up correctly for your server configuration, and contact your host

Answer (score 1):

This happens when Wordpress cannot directly (via php) create files inside the `wp-content` directory.

Wordpress asks for FTP credentials to try and upload "manually" the files, you should provide the hostname of the ftp server (example: `ftp.yourdomain.com`), username and password. Of course you have to have an FTP server set up, which is usually straightforward on an shared hosting. If you are inside a self-hosted environment (i.e. VPS, AWS ec2 instance) you should solve this at the root of the problem:

To solve this you have to set as `755` the permissions to  `wp-content` ( `chmod -R 755 /you/html/root/wp-content`) and make sure that the owner of the directory is the user as whom apache/nginx/php-fpm runs with the `ls -l` command.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress asks for an FTP account there. So you have to enter the data for the FTP account. You will get that data from your provider. Mostly you have entered it already to your FTP client.

Comment: I am getting a hostname by typing into terminal "hostname" and it gives me some hostname. But it does not work for WordPress. How would I get FTP hostname from Amazon Web Services?

Comment: How did you upload und install wordpress on your server?

Answer (score 0):

if wordpress is installed to the server you are connecting to for amazon, make sure you have ftp daemon running and even installed first.

if you do, then it should be as simple as putting in `localhost` as the hostname. it is local and does not go outside the DNS.

You need to give more information on the configuration of your network. Is it a standalone server, what type of server, what o/s or is it clustered and if so how.

If you do have ftp running have you setup users and permissions to the correct directories that wordpress is installed to.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above methods but it didn't work for me. What worked for me is adding this line `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in `wp-config.php` file.

Add this line at the end of the file. Since it is my local XAMPP set up I made this change. However, if it is a live site on shared hosting then double-check with your host before doing so.